# CSS rules not getting applied

Tags: html, css, django, nginx

For some reason my CSS rule is not being applied. I know the css page is getting found and loaded into the browser.  Just the rule isn't being applied. I've tried just doing a h1 rule but not my rules aren't being applied to the pages. I'm using uwsgii and nginx on a ubuntu 12.04 server. I've collected my static,  restarted uwsgi and nginx, I've changed the rule, I've added !important, I'm missing something and I don't know what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Currently my css/base.css looks like this - I've also tried just changing the color to red but notta.

```
.evil {
    color: #c5e3bf;
}
```

My base template - looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block sub_title %}{% endblock %} Awesome title</title>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet/css" type="text/css" href='{% static "css/base.css" %}'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jquery-2.1.0.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'Underscore.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'Restangular.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/ng-sign-in/app.js' %}"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <body>
        <span class="evil">Punch something, you know you wanna. Just do it.</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: I commented out all the scripts, only leaving the

```
<link rel="stylesheet/css" type="text/css" href='/static/css/base.css'>
```

still not applying the rule.

UPDATE: Changed from running on nginx to running a localhost - still no luck
My settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My URLS:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',     
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls),     
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) # this was added in per request -- notta.
```

Comment: You included AngularJS after all the `<link>` element using AngularJS, try putting AngularJS at the top of the `<head>` element.

Comment: Tried that still broken. Then tried putting the <link rel... at the bottom of the header element, still notta.

Comment: Try putting the style in the head `<style> .evil {color:red} </style>` as a preliminary test. You have high level stuff going on here... lets get back to basics for a second...

Comment: @sheriffderek - That worked. So that's something!

Comment: Yeah. So you know your routing is off. ... uh --- your {% %} stuff... what is that? angular stuff? If you are loading angular after those fancy placeholders... how will it know what it is?

Comment: What about just putting in the real URL of your css as a second test.

Comment: the {%%} is django template tags.  Shouldn't it know that it's css rules by the <link rel="sytlesheet/css" type="text/css"? And the file is being found, I can click on the href in the browser to go the page.

Comment: @sheriffderek - Changed the django tag to be <link rel="stylesheet/css" type="text/css" href='/static/css/base.css'> -- still no using the rule :( :( :(

Comment: Remove all of the stuff except the `<link>` to the css. None of that other stuff has anything to do with this problem. Just comment them out.

Comment: I did. Still not being applied.

Comment: Show us your STATIC_ROOT and your STATIC_URL from setetings.py and your urlpatterns from urls.py

Comment: STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'  My static files are being found and served - I know this because my js files are being served.

Comment: If you know that your file is being sent but not applied then check the `content-type` header for your css file, it could be being sent as `text/html` instead of `text/css`

Comment: Removing the /css from the rel= attribute fixed the problem. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) in your urls.py:

> urlpatterns = patterns('', #Your URLS)  **+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)**

Comment: My understanding is that this should only be applied in development when your using your ./manage.py runserver to run a server locally. And you don't need it when you're using nginx + uwsigi? Is that not correct?